# How to convert a File type into a String during constructor chaining?

Tags: java

The second constructor takes in a String name, so I would have to convert this into a File type in the this()call, but how do I do this?

```
 // constructors
public example(File title){
    nameOfFile= title ;
// calling constructor 
public example(String name)
    this(name);
```

Comment: Assuming you need the name of the file and not its content `File.getName()` should work. In your case `nameOfFile = title.getName();`

Comment: I'm confused. Why wouldn't a simple `this(new File(name))` do it for you? You do know how to create a [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#constructor.summary) object, right? There are only 4 overloads, so it's not like identifying the one that takes a `String` is difficult to find, and it is the most commonly used one too.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a `File`'s constructor on the string argument:

```java
public class Example { 
    private File nameOfFile;

    public Example(File title) {
        nameOfFile = title;
    }

    public Example(String name) {
        this(new File(name));
    }
}
```